# Multiple same maximum amplitudes of a pendulum

Tags: waves

In the pic, you see a sphere freely hanging from the ceiling by a string. According to the simple definition of a pendulum, it seems to be okay to call it a pendulum.

An instantaneous force, shown by the red arrow, is applied to the sphere.

The sphere swings and eventually passes points A,B and C. ( I am aware that the position function is a continuous function with billions of points but let us assume that there are only 3 for the sake of this question.)

Let 'C' be the amplitude position and is exactly 2.90210 inches from the equilibrium position. ( The amplitude being the maximum displacement of the sphere from its equilibrium position.)

Here is the question:

Do pendulums have only one maximum Amplitude point or can a pendulum swing to the same exact maximum amplitude point a few times?

In other words, if a pendulum swung 2.90210 inches from equilibrium, in subsequent swings, can it swing back again to exactly 2.90210 inches from equilibrium?

I think that a freely moving pendulum, in real life, will have only one maximum amplitude point with all the other subsequent points being a tinsy little bit less than the maximum amplitude point; due to air friction and other energy losses.

What do you guys think?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.
If the pendulum was an ideal object with no friction, it would always swing back to the maximum amplitude (point C).

In reality the pendulum will lose energy due to friction with air, with the rope or other effect so it will reach its maximum amplitude only once. We call this "damped harmonic motion". [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_harmonic_motion#:~:text=Damped%20harmonic%20motion%20is%20a,energy%20goes%20into%20thermal%20energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_harmonic_motion#:%7E:text=Damped%20harmonic%20motion%20is%20a,energy%20goes%20into%20thermal%20energy).

There is a neat lesson by Walter Lewin where he demonstrates exactly this, check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77ZF50ve6rs